# Multiclass classification with junk class

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, multiclass-classification

I would like to do multiclass classification but I'm in a weird spot, I'm basically trying to classify code as good or bad where there are multiple classes for bad code but there will only be one good class. It's almost like binary classification where its either good or bad but there are multiple cases for bad code. I'm wondering if making the good class the same size as all other bad classes combined will be feasible or if there is another method to go about this.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence off-topic here; please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 0):

If you only care if a given code instance is *good* or *bad*, you might want to check out semi-supervised anomaly detection, where the *good* code is considered anomalous. It might be referred to as "Other-vs-One", which is not as common as "One-vs-Other", but regardless it is worth a shot.